# read dataframe string object data to json format in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have string data in dataframe, would like to read it as json format and load it to another dataframe.

sample :

```
.       {"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
        |{"request":{"pat...|
```

Schema:
root

```
         |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

new_df = spark.read.json(df.select("col1").rdd.map(lambda r: r.json))

[image]

Comment: what is the method `json` belonging to the `r` object ? `r` is supposed to be a string, it does not have a `json` property or method ...

Comment: @rahul  i got this error after executing 

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 35.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 35.0 (TID 52, lvshdc2dn2446.lvs.paypalinc.com): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 111, in main

Comment: It should not throw the error. It is working fine for me. Added the snap. Are you doing the same ?

Answer (score 0):

i got below error while executing the command that you have provided
(df3 = sqlContext.read.json(df2.select("first").rdd.map(lambda r: r.json)

An error occurred while calling o1324.json.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 54.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 54.0 (TID 75, lvshdc2dn2559.lvs.paypalinc.com): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/hadoop03/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1625855466178_519726/container_e330_1625855466178_519726_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
process()
File "/hadoop03/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1625855466178_519726/container_e330_1625855466178_519726_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
File "/hadoop03/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1625855466178_519726/container_e330_1625855466178_519726_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 133, in dump_stream
for obj in iterator:
File "/hadoop26/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1625855466178_519726/container_e330_1625855466178_519726_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 181, in func
File "", line 19, in 
File "/hadoop03/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1625855466178_519726/container_e330_1625855466178_519726_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1269, in **getattr**
raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: json